# Mutate dynamically created variable dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyeval

I am trying to create a function in which I summarise several columns in a dataframe using several functions and then mutate the output of these functions later.

A simpler example is given below:

```
group_mean_plus_one <- function(df, groups, var){
  
  df %>% 
    group_by(across({{groups}})) %>%
    
    summarise(across({{ var }}, 
                     .fns = list(mean = ~mean(.x, na.rm=TRUE),
                                 sd = ~sd(.x, na.rm=TRUE)),
                     .names = "{.col}_{.fn}")) %>%
    
    mutate("mean_plus_one_{{var}}" := !!rlang::expr("{{var}}_mean + 1"))
  
}

tibble(mtcars) %>%
  group_mean_plus_one(groups = cyl, var = hp)
```

Here the idea is that we group by each of the variables in `group` and summarise each of the variables in `var` using the given functions.

Further on we wish to refer to the the variables created in the `summarise` block and `mutate` new variables from these. However, I am struggling with referring to these dynamically created variable names from the `summarise` block.

Running the above returns:

```
# A tibble: 3 x 4
    cyl hp_mean hp_sd mean_plus_one_hp
  <dbl>   <dbl> <dbl> <chr>           
1     4    82.6  20.9 {{var}}_mean + 1
2     6   122.   24.3 {{var}}_mean + 1
3     8   209.   51.0 {{var}}_mean + 1
```

when instead I want it to return:

```
# A tibble: 3 x 4
    cyl hp_mean hp_sd mean_plus_one_hp
  <dbl>   <dbl> <dbl>            <dbl>
1     4    82.6  20.9             83.6
2     6   122.   24.3            123. 
3     8   209.   51.0            210.
```

Any help is much appreciated, thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 3):

We could convert to string, and use `.data`

```
group_mean_plus_one <- function(df, groups, var){
  
  var1 <- rlang::as_string(rlang::ensym(var))
  df %>% 
    group_by(across({{groups}})) %>%
    
    summarise(across({{ var }}, 
                     .fns = list(mean = ~mean(.x, na.rm=TRUE),
                                 sd = ~sd(.x, na.rm=TRUE)),
                     .names = "{.col}_{.fn}")) %>%
         mutate("mean_plus_one_{{var}}" :=  .data[[str_c(var1, "_mean")]] + 1)         
  
}
```

-testing

```
tibble(mtcars) %>%
  group_mean_plus_one(groups = cyl, var = hp)
# A tibble: 3 x 4
    cyl hp_mean hp_sd mean_plus_one_hp
  <dbl>   <dbl> <dbl>            <dbl>
1     4    82.6  20.9             83.6
2     6   122.   24.3            123. 
3     8   209.   51.0            210.
```